# Linking shared, static, and dynamic library

Tags: c++, g++, static-linking, dynamic-linking, spidermonkey

I built and installed the source code of spidermonkey, I want to link its library and its include folder with my C++ application, so I wrote this command on linux

```
 g++ -I/home/SpiderMonkey/js-1.8.5/js/src/dist/include 
 -L/home/SpiderMonkey/js1.8.5/js/src/dist/lib -lmozjs185  helloworld.cpp -o
```

but it gives me undefined reference error, so what is the problem with this command:
the path which the src code was built in is home/SpiderMonkey/js1.8.5/src
and when I installed the src code, its libs and include folder exist now in usr/local/lib and usr/local/include/js respectively, so which path should I use in the command to compile my hellowrorld.cpp. 
Also, I found 3 libraries with the same name but with different extension:

```
libname.so, libname.so.1.0, libname.so.1.0.0 and libname.a
```

which library should I use and what are the differences?

Comment: *.so are dynamic libraries, *.a are static

Comment: and what about .so.1.0 and .so.1.0.0 ? and which one should I use ?
the static one or dynamic one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the libraries *after* your `main.cpp` on the compilation command. The linker determines which symbols to pull out of those libraries based on the objects it's already seen, left to right.

As for your addendum question:

- `libname.a` is for static linking.
- `libname.so`, `libname.so.1.0` and `libname.so.1.0.0` are all the same file, just with names that give you an increasing level of version information granularity.

Which to use is beyond the scope of this answer, but you can find plenty of information about that already existing on the web.

Comment: it worked in the compilation process, but when I tried to run my helloworld.cpp using ./helloworld
it gives me this error :
error while loading shared libraries : libname.so.1.0 cannot open shared object file, no such file or directory

Comment: what is the problem now?

Comment: @sara: You need to put the library in the proper place within your system, or use `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` if you want to temporarily use the current directory for libraries. You should find some reading material on how to use libraries.

Comment: Thank you again the problem was solved when I use this command as you said 
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib